# Dart has Object? but no named top type?

Tags: dart, types

I was reading the [Understanding null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#top-and-bottom) documentation about top and bottom types. It says:

> Since `Object` is non-nullable now, it is no longer a top type. `Null` is not a subtype of it. Dart has no *named* top type. If you need a top type, you want `Object?`.

It makes sense that I can use `Object?` in practice as a top type, but I don't understand the meaning of not having a **named** top type. `Object` is a subtype of `Object?`, isn't it? It feels like there is something happening behind the scenes that I don't understand. What's the problem with just naming `Object?` as the top type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "named" type is one which can be denoted by an identifier. It has a *name*, not just a description. The type `Object?` does not have such a name, it only exists as the combination of the `Object` type and the `?` type modifier. You can't possibly point to the *declaration* of the type, and it's not a "nominative type", one defined by the declaration that the name refers to. Instead it's a structural type, each occurrence of `Object?` *introduces* the type to the program. It exists without being declared, which is why it's considered non-"named".

Arguably, both `dynamic` and `void` are named top-types (`void` is technically not an *identifier* because it's a reserved word, but `dynamic` is an identifier and it refers to a "declaration" in `dart:core` - even if it's a synthetic declaration that cannot be expressed in the language itself, it still exists in that scope).
It's just that both types have some side-effects (allowing dynamic invocation and not allowing any invocation), so they're not *neutral* top types to use if all you care about is encompassing all values. That's why the text recommends using `Object?` as the type representing "any value".